# Module over a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm trying to prove the following:

If $D = K[x]$ where $K$ is a field, and $M \subset D^n$ is a submodule for some $n \geq 2$ then $L = D^n/M$ is Artinian iff the torsion module of $L$ is isomorphic to $M$.

So far, since $K$ is a field we have that $D$ is a PID and then any module $L$ over D is of the form $D^k \times T(L)$, but I don't see how I can proceed from here. Any help will be welcome.

Thank You!

Comment: As $D$ is a domain, no nonzero submodule of $D^n$ is torsion. And $M$ is not a submodule of $L$, so the question is ill-posed. Please, fix it.

Comment: Dear @egreg sorry but I don't uderstand what you mean, the questionar says that M is the torsion of L and not of $D^n$, I can't ser the problem...

Comment: $M$ is *not* a submodule of $L$, so it can't be its torsion.

Comment: I see it, I should say tha the torsion is isomorphic to M... I will correct it, thanks.

Comment: This question means nothing, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Prove the following:

> $L$ is artinian $\iff$ $L$ is torsion $\iff$ $\operatorname{rank}M=n$.

Comment: dear @user26857,sorry for the silly question but, by torsion you mean torsion free, I searched the definition of torsion module and can't find it...

Comment: @Charles  A module is torsion if all its elements are torsion. In our notation, $L$ is torsion if $T(L)=L$. (See [here](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Torsion_submodule).)

Comment: thank you again user26857! But then my question have a serious problem, because since M is a submodule of a free module, M is a torsion free module, then M can not be a torsion module right? wich means that this statement is false?